# ExtJS Floating Panel - relative positioning

Tags: javascript, extjs, css-float, extjs5

How do i get a floating Component to position itself relative to its parent Container and maintain its relative position to the Container when the Container is moved?

e.g. when the Container is scrolled up or down

At the moment the floating Component seems to position itself relative to the Viewport (even though i've set 'fixed:false').

Framework: ExtJS 5.1

Comment: Post your code please.